# ng-repeat keeps updating from no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a semi-chat in AngularJS and Firebase. For displaying the messages I used `<li ng-repeat="message in messages">`. I noticed that any change in the NEW message input (which is NOT in the scope of the `li`) triggers a refresh(?) of   creating the chat.

```
<ul>   
    <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
        {{message.auther}}: <span ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet(urlify(message.text))"></span>    
        <!-- diss/like a message -->
        <button ng-click="message.like = !message.like; invertLike($index)">
            <span ng-show="!message.like">Like Button</span>
            <span ng-show="message.like">Dislike Button</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- push a new message onto the array -->
<form ng-submit="addMessage()">
    name: <input ng-model="auther" /> <br />
    message: <input ng-model="newMessageText" />
    <button type="submit">Add Message</button>
</form>
```

(The code of deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet and urlify can be found here: http://pastebin.com/wLRLHfHy)

Is there a way to stop that refresh? Thanks

Comment: Please include the minimal code **in** the question. Linking to it is not enough, since links tend to rot. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The minimal code is in the question. The pastebin is for 2 functions that are not related to the ng-repeat.